# Installed PHP mbstring but not recognized

Tags: php, nginx, centos, mbstring

I'm on Centos 7 running PHP 5.4. My webserver is Nginx.

The error log in my nginx says:

> 2018/08/30 04:07:18 [error] 12342#0: *403 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Stripe needs the Multibyte String PHP extension.' in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/s2member-pro/src/includes/classes/gateways/stripe/stripe-sdk/lib/Stripe.php:14

I've already installed it with the following command. I've rebooted nginx and I ran this command again just to confirm it's installed.

```
# yum install php-mbstring
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * epel: ewr.edge.kernel.org
 * extras: mirror.vcu.edu
 * updates: ewr.edge.kernel.org
Nothing to do
```

Any idea why I am still getting the error `Stripe needs the Multibyte String PHP extension.`?

Do I need to configure something in nginx.conf or anything?

Comment: What do you mean by "rebootet nginx"? you restarted the service? nginx does not oeprate php as a module (it can't), but typically inside a fastcgi container or similar. You need to restart that.

Comment: Are you able to check `phpinfo()` and `mbstring` is listed there?